# Proper Usage of Entity Manager from EntityManagerFactory

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, entitymanager

I am having some trouble understanding the proper usage of entity manager when querying for objects and or deleting/creating. Right now for any database transactions I have several service methods that open and close new entity managers like so:

```
public static Long getCountApplicants(String active){

    EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
    long value = (Long) entityManager.createQuery("select count(distinct a) from    Applicant a  where a.active = " +active).getSingleResult();
    System.out.println("get count app query");
    entityManager.close();
    return value;
}
```

Since I have a Java EE app with a persistence.xml file that defines my unit, why can't I declare only one from my factory and use it throughout the life of my app? Is there any performance or memory leak issues with using just one of these objects?

Update:

I am using the following stack, Spring Framework/JPA Eclipselink

Comment: `EntityManager` is not thread-safe.

Comment: so by closing it every time i am avoiding lock issues?

Comment: I'm clueless about this stuff as well, but I think I noticed a form of memory leak by which the cache of objects in EntityManager continued to grow.

Comment: Its the exact same thing that i have been noticing in my test environment as well. Using the spring framework i get constant cached instance calls from the 'EMF' and it slows down my queries every once in a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short: Since you're using Spring, you're better off defining the Entity Manager as an attribute of your DAO like so:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;
```

Your code then becomes:

```
public static Long getCountApplicants(String active){
    long value = (Long) em.createQuery("select count(distinct a) from    Applicant a  where a.active = " +active).getSingleResult();
    System.out.println("get count app query");
    return value;
}
```

This will work only with Non Extended Persistence Contexts.
The EntityManager injected by Spring will be threadsafe.
Whether you need to configure an `LocalEntityManagerFactorBean` application-managed or `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` container-managed Entity Manager is just a matter of configuration in the Spring configuration files.

Comment: Does this mean I dont need to explicitly close the em anymore?

Answer (score 1):

EntityManager is generally not threadsafe when application managed.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqw.html

However, if you're using a container managed version, it should be.   You would inject it:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;
```

Spring is one such container that can do this.  The link above is a helpful resource.